# Find users from AD OU and for each user find Logon and Logout Times in Eventlogs

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am searching a script which takes all users from an OU of Active Directory as

```psh
$searchBase = "ou=users,ou=ABC,OU=Gardezi,DC=Gardezi,dc=com"
$searchTree = "ou=XXDepartment,", "ou=CSDepartment,"        
foreach ($ou in $searchTree) {
  write-host "searching in OU: $ou $searchBase"
  $name = $ou
  $name = $name.subString($name.IndexOf("=")+1,$name.Indexof(",")-3)
}
```

and for each user find the logon and logoff times through EventLog on 2 of my computers during last week. Logon requirement should meet the EventId=4624 and logon type=2 0r 10 as

```psh
(($_.InstanceId -eq 4624) -and ($_.Message -match "Logon Type:2")) -or
(($_.InstanceId -eq 4624) -and ($_.Message -match "Logon Type:10")
```

for say 7 days.

Can any one please complete this for me?

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx). The `Get-EventLog` cmdlet has a parameter `-ComputerName` that accepts a list of computer names. The time range can be restricted via the `-Before` and `-After` parameters.

```psh
$username = 'foo'
$hosts    = 'HostA', 'HostB', ...
$age      = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

Get-EventLog -Log Security -Computer $hosts -InstanceId 4624 -After $age | ? {
  $_.Message -match "account name:\s+$username\s" -and
  $_.Message -match 'logon type:\s+(2|10)\s'
}
```

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers. Dear Sir thanks for your reply. Can you please make the complte code for me I will be highly grateful Email address: qasim.gardezi@hotmail.com

Comment: SO is a place where we help you fix problems with the code you wrote, not write code for you. Consider merging the above with the rest of your code your homework.

Comment: Right Sir :( I dont know how to do that

Comment: wieches : Sir I want to add the logout condition and also for checking each user how will it work as I want for each user the Logon also logout time. If I apply If Else then only 1 conditions will be true? Please help me with that ..May I apply switch here If yes how please?